# How fast does this Markov chain converge?

Tags: matrices, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

[image]

[image]

Observe the above a Markov chain and limiting matrix of it. Finding the limiting matrix if it exists is easy but I am curious as to how fast this given matrix converges to its limiting matrix. Is there a way to find the number of transitions that would give a matrix that is very close to the limiting matrix for an accepted amount of error? I hope someone could suggest me some methods or references that would help me determine this. Thanks in advance

Comment: $M$ has distinct eigenvalues and is diagonalizable, hence so is the limiting matrix.

Comment: @copper.hat : I don't agree. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, $\lambda^k$ either diverges or converges to $0$ or $1$, so there is not a lot or room for the eigenvalues of the limiting matrix. Btw, $M$ is a stochastic irreducible and aperiodic matrix, so $M^k$ converges (exponentially fast) to a projector of rank $1$.

Comment: Since the matrix $M$ has eigenvalues $-1/3$ and $-2/3$, the rate of convergence is essentially determined by how fast $(1/3)^k$ and $(2/3)^k$ converge to zero with $k\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: @Ahriman: I'm not sure what you are disagreeing with. The eigenvalues of $M$ are $1,-{1 \over 3}, -{2 \over 3}$. Both $M$ and the limit $M_\infty$ are diagonalizable, in fact its easy to compute the eigenvectors. Hence it is straightforward to bound $\|M^k-M_\infty\|$ using any suitable norm.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Can you provide some theory to back your answer? Thanks

Comment: @DonaldEdwards I guess I did in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trace and the determinant of $M$ are $0$ and $\frac29$ respectively. Since $M$ is a transition matrix, $1$ is an eigenvalue, hence the sum and product of the two other eigenvalues are $-1$ and $\frac29$ respectively. This implies that these eigenvalues are $-\frac23$ and $-\frac13$.

Thus, the difference $M^k-\Pi$ is of order $\left(\frac23\right)^k$ when $k\to\infty$, where $\Pi=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}M^n$ is given in the question. Here one can define the *size* of a matrix of any size as the sum of the absolute values of its entries.

In particular, for every vector $V$, the difference $M^kV-\Pi V$ is of order *at most* $\left(\frac23\right)^k$ when $k\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I use this to find the minimum transitions I need to get as much as close to the limiting vector?

Comment: The exact number will depend on the distance on matrices you use and/or on the vector V (as not so subtly indicated in my answer). When the error $\varepsilon$ goes to zero, the number of transitions needed is $O(\log(1/\varepsilon)/\log(3/2))$.

Comment: Thanks again. Is there any book I can look up regarding this? I would much appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Well, about any text on matrices, I would say. But this is not needed to understand the answer here, is it?

Comment: Nope not in particular but I just want to study more deep in to it go through the relevant theorems

Comment: I cannot seem to find how O(log(1/ε)/log(3/2)) was derived. Any theorem involved?

Comment: Solve $\varepsilon=\left(\frac23\right)^k$.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Best answer thus far. I went through some notes and I guess you have come up with this using the spectral representation of the matrix right? Can this be used even if the matrix cannot be diagonalized?

Comment: Even if the matrix cannot be diagonalized it can be made triangular with a diagonal of eigenvalues, say in Jordan form. Thus the largest |λ| with λ not 1 still rules the convergence rate to Π, up to logarithmic corrections.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, assume that $M$ is diagonalisable and hence there exists a nonsingular matrix $X$ such that
$$
M=X\begin{bmatrix}\Lambda&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix}X^{-1},
$$
where $\Lambda=\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_r)$ such that $|\lambda_i|<1$ and $I$ is the identity matrix. Let $\|\cdot\|$ be a sub-multiplicative matrix norm such that the norm of a diagonal matrix is equal to the maximal absolute value of its diagonal entries (this is satisfied, e.g., by any $p$-norm such as the spectral norm). Then
$$
M^k=X\begin{bmatrix}\Lambda^k&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix}X^{-1},
\quad
M^{\infty}\equiv\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}M^k=X\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&I\end{bmatrix}X^{-1}.
$$
Then
$$
M^{k}-M^{\infty}=X\begin{bmatrix}\Lambda^k&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}X^{-1}
$$
and hence
$$
\|M^{k}-M^{\infty}\|\leq\|X\|\|X^{-1}\|\left\|\begin{bmatrix}\Lambda^k&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\right\|
=\kappa(X)\rho^k,
$$
where $\kappa(X)\equiv\|X\|\|X^{-1}\|$ is the condition number of the eigenvector basis $X$ and $\rho\equiv\max\{|\lambda_i|:\;i=1,\ldots,r\}$.
Hence a sufficient condition for having $\|M^k-M^{\infty}\|\leq\epsilon<1$ is to have $\kappa(X)\rho^k\leq\epsilon$ and thus
$$
k\geq\frac{\log[\epsilon/\kappa(X)]}{\log\rho}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

When you found $M^k$ for this matrix, you likely used a diagonalization argument; you have $M = U \Lambda U^{-1}$ where $\Lambda$ is diagonal. In this case $M^k = U \Lambda^k U^{-1}$ and if 
$$\Lambda = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_3 \end{pmatrix}$$
then
$$\Lambda = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1^k & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2^k & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_3^k \end{pmatrix}.$$
So,
$$
M^k = U \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1^k & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2^k & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_3^k \end{pmatrix} U^{-1}.
$$
This shows that, in a certain sense, the "speed" of convergence of $M^k$ can be explored by considering the "speed" of convergence of $\lambda_1^k, \lambda_2^k,$ and $\lambda_3^k$.

Comment: Can the EXACT speed be calculated from this?