# Convergence time of a Markov chain

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, self-learning, markov-chains

We know that a regular Markov chains converges to a unique matrix. The convergence time maybe finite or infinite. My interest is in the case where the convergence time is finite. How can we accurately determine this time or in other words the number of transitions for convergence? I am interested to go through the relevant materials needed to determine different methods that maybe out there to calculate this. If anyone could suggest a good reference to start off with I would be delighted. Any assistance will be welcomed.

Comment: A simple example: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/814994

Comment: @Did Thank you but I am not familiar with the method you have used where you have taken the order of differences between powers of the transition matrix and the limiting matrix. What is the theory related to this? Any topics of a book that may help me?

Comment: Any book on finite Markov chains, really. But the idea is simple: if the transition matrix was diagonal (it never is but this is the relevant phenomenon, believe me), the diagonal would be (1,a,b,...) with |a|<1, |b|<1, etc., hence the nth power would be the diagonal (1,a^n,b^n,...) and the limit would be the diagonal (1,0,0,...) hence the size of their difference would be ruled by |a|^n for the maximum |a| available.

Comment: @Did This however is different from mixing times right?

Comment: Are you aware of the spectral representation of a matrix?

Comment: @Heisenberg yes I guess I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the following thesis it will help. What you are looking for can be found from page 16 on-wards. Hope this helps.
http://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/~lorek/files/lorek_thesis.pdf

Comment: Thanks. I will go through it and see how relevant it is to me

Comment: This is excellent just what I was looking for! Thanks Heisenberg

Comment: @DonaldEdwards You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by distinguishing finite and infinite convergence time - no interesting chain will converge exactly in finite time, and of course no closeness to the limit before "infinite time" is essentially no convergence.

Anyway, the question you are asking is essentially about how fast powers of stochastic matrices will converge.

I found this lecture where they prove exponential convergence: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-262-discrete-stochastic-processes-spring-2011/video-lectures/lecture-7-finite-state-markov-chains-the-matrix-approach/

Comment: Yes even a number of transitions that may give a matrix which is close to the limiting matrix will do

Comment: but how do I find that number is the question

Comment: I just edited in [this lecture](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-262-discrete-stochastic-processes-spring-2011/video-lectures/lecture-7-finite-state-markov-chains-the-matrix-approach/) which gives a bound for convergence dependent on minimal elements.